# Running Imacro From Script on Webpage (Not the plugin)

Tags: imacros

I am trying to run Imacro on my works intranet. I have installed the Firefox plugin, the IE plugin the Chrome plugin. I have also installed the trail version of Imacro.

Basically what I need to do is to kick off a imacro script from a button click, I do not want the user to have to open the plugin and choose the file from the plugin window. The users WILL have the plugins, but I just want it to kick off from a html button click.

But the problem is all the examples say iimPlay(..) but iimPlay is undefined in all browsers, even after everything is installed (I cant find a imacros.js file to reference)

I want to be able to store the macro (.iim) file inside a directory on the webpage, and then run iimPlay() from a js file stored on the same webpage.

Is that possible?